# How to prove $\frac{1}{m+n+1}-\frac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)} ≤ \frac{4}{45}$?

Tags: inequality, natural-numbers

If $m$ and $n$ are any two positive integers then how do we show that the inequality $$\frac{1}{m+n+1}-\frac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)} ≤ \frac{4}{45}$$ always holds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let
$$f(m,n)=\dfrac{1}{m+n+1}-\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)}$$
then we easy to 
$$f(1,1)=f(1,2)=f(2,1)=\dfrac{1}{12}\le\dfrac{4}{45}$$
so,when $m,n\ge 2,$,then we let $j=m+n+2\ge 6$

then
$$f(m,n)=\dfrac{1}{m+n+1}-\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)}\le\dfrac{1}{j-1}-\dfrac{4}{j^2}\le\dfrac{4}{45}$$
It is clearly,
because $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{4}{x^2}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\dfrac{8}{x^3}=\dfrac{8(x-1)^2-x^3}{x^3(x-1)^2}<0,x\ge 6$$let
 where $j\ge 6$.

Comment: math110: how do we show (1/(j-1))-(4/j^2) ≤ 4/45 ?

Comment: $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{4}{x^2},x\ge 6\Longrightarrow f'(x)<0$$

Comment: math110: Hm , I can see that for x≥8 , x^3≥8x^2>8x^2-88=8x^2-96+8>8x^2-16x+8=8(x-1)^2 , so 8(x-1)^2 -x^3 <0 for x≥8 and trivial verification for x=6,7 ; am I doing right ?

Comment: when $x=6$,then $8(x-1)^2=8\cdot 25=200<6^3=216$,when $x=7$,then $8(x-1)^2=8\cdot 36=288<7^3=343$

Comment: Ok , got it , thank you it was very helpful.